# How can I manage the horizontal scroll on a carousel in a mobile website?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, scroll

I have a website with a carousel of images. On mobile, I'd like to "move" this carousel when I move the finger in horizontal.

This carousel is ready to work, already done with jquery (but handle with a click handlers). I need handle it with horizontal movement.

Is there a jquery plugin that allow me to handle this movement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery mobile you can easily use swipe events.

Example:

```
$("#carousel").bind('swipeleft',function(event, ui){

});
```

If you are not using jQM take a look at this framework: http://wipetouch.codeplex.com/. It is lightweight. There are also few other frameworks but I never used them. Few months ago I have created a jQM app with carousel and jQM swipe events. It works just fine, without performance problems.

**EDIT :**

Here's an working carousel example (With swipeleft event, you can also implement swiperight but this is only an example) for you: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/Np3G4/ I have tested it on my PC (just drag your mouse to the left) and Android 4.1 (swipe to left), but from my past experience it also works on iPad (so i believe it should work on iPhone). This code is combination of this [carousel](http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/download.php) and my implementation of common jQM swipe events. You can still use jQM framework only for swipe events.

**EDIT 2:**

This version works on iPad without jQuery mobile framework: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/qCB6w/. It uses touchwipe framework: http://www.netcu.de/jquery-touchwipe-iphone-ipad-library.I hope this is all you need to make it work.

Comment: Then take a look at other framework. If you want I can create an example for you but wipetouch will be enough.

Comment: I think I've done! I don't understand why it calls both wipeLeft and wipeRight when the page is loaded...

Comment: Uhm, tried on iPhone, nothing happens! Seems that wipetouch doesnt works :(

Comment: Give me a sec to finish an example for you.

Comment: Can you give an example without jquery mobile? I won't it, it changes all my layout...

Comment: Or, can you tell me how to insert jquery mobile without "manage" my elements (as ajax call for links, and so on)

Comment: I will create another example for you when I come home

Comment: Well, I'd like the jQuery Mobile. Just, I want to use only the functions I need. So, for example, how can I disable that "link-ajax" transformation?

Comment: My last example is not using jQuery mobile, take a look at it. Better forget about jQM if there is any chance it will cause you problems.

Comment: No, this last example doesnt works well! In fact, I can scroll on "vertical" when I'm over the fruits. It gets the horizontal handle and all is frozen! I need your first example...but blocking jquery mobile default acts...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643948/is-it-possible-use-jquery-mobile-only-for-some-functions/13644417#13644417

Comment: Take care some events work on iPhone only and some work on Android. For example tap works on Android but not on iPhone, while touchstart works on iPhone. This could be a problem, play little bit with events, you will find right combination.

Comment: Uhm yeah, but if swipeleft doesnt works, the game is finished :(

Comment: Swipeleft and Swiperight do work, I used them for my mobile app (Android, iPhone) with carousel I showed you in example.

Comment: Tried on Samsung Galaxy S3 (so Android), and swipeleft/right is not triggered :(

Comment: That's funny : jquery.mobile-1.1.1.js works perfectly! With jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js it doesnt works :O

Comment: There is some issue on you code, with (tested) on iPhone. Try to scroll the page up/down many times, quickly, or slow, keeping the finger pressed for long time. Than try to scroll the carousel: it seems to be crashed/frozen. Why this? how can I fix it?

Comment: P.S. I notice that it's a carousel fault, because the event swipe are taken! Why this for you?

Comment: Quick scrolling is an event problem (and to some part carousel problem, it isn't built with numerous swipe events in mind). My example is a simple one. When swipe event is triggered swipe event must be removed from carousel until animation finishes. In my example you will find this line: "duration: 800", event must be removed during this animation time.

Comment: Also don't forge my example is a simple one, it was built to show you how swipe events can be used in context of carousel, not to be reused again. My original code is much more complex then this.

Comment: Well, so how can I fix this trouble?

Comment: Swipe elements is always called! The problem is in the carousel man! After some scrolling, it won't move :(

Comment: What I've also noticed is that onBefore is not called after some swipe...this is the broken link between carousel and swipe...

Comment: It was a IoS6 Timeout bug! Found a code to fix it! Thank you!