# Is it possible use jQuery Mobile only for "some" functions?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I need jQuery mobile only for function like `swipeleft`.

In fact, when I load jQuery Mobile, it edit the whole template of the website; changing all links as ajax request, and tons of functionality that I don't need at all!

Is it possible to load this plugins without default behavior? Just for using its some functions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You couldn't wait for me to give you an answer in last question. ;)

To make answer short, yes you can. Go to this link:

http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/[1](http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/) and build yourself custom jQM library. Only works with jQM 1.1.1 and 1.2. Take only Events -> touch.